# Shibboleth authentication in Rails

Tags: ruby, shibboleth

I am having a struggle getting this to work so I've created a hell-world Rails app to try and get this to work.

Here's the repo with the code that is not working: https://github.com/pitosalas/shibtry

Here's what I've done starting from an empty Rails application:

1. I've added two gems to gem files:

   ```
   gem 'omniauth-shibboleth'
   gem 'rack-saml'
   ```
2. I got the shibboleth meta data from my university's web site and converted it using shib_conv.rb into the corresponding YAML: ./config.yml
3. I've updated routes adding `get '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'`
4. I've put a breakpoint at `SessionController#create`
5. I've added initializers: omniauth.rb:

   ```
   Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
     provider :shibboleth, {
       :shib_session_id_field     => "Shib-Session-ID",
       :shib_application_id_field => "Shib-Application-ID",
       :debug                     => true,
       :extra_fields => [
         :"unscoped-affiliation",
         :entitlement
       ]
     }
   end
   ```
6. I've added rack_sam.rb initializer:

   ```
   Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_after Rack::ETag, Rack::Saml,
     { :metadata => "#{Rails.root}/config/metadata.yml"}
   ```
7. Now, run the server and go to `http://0.0.0.0:3000/auth/shibboleth` and I get an error:

   ```
   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass'
   ```

   which is traced back to this line in rack-saml/misc/onelogin_setting.rb line 13 which is:

   ```
   settings.idp_sso_target_url = @metadata['saml2_http_redirect']
   ```

   in other words, looking for the metadata hash for that key. It happens that in my metadata.yml file that key is present, but by the time I get to this onelogin_setting.rb line 13, `@metadata` is nil (it should contain the contents of the file) and consequently that key doesn't exist.

And that's where, for now, the trail dries up.

Comment: hi, did you ever get this working? i could really use some help in order to set this up with my university as well.

Comment: Yes, I did it in a totally different way. I used google's own mechanism to allow an app to log in. https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/

Comment: gotcha, unfortunately i need to do this via shibboleth for an app at my university. if you have any potential hints or clues onto how to make it work, i am all ears. I am also getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

I bypassed Shibboleth totally. My goal was to allow login to my universities authentication system specifically to allow students to log in with their student login, which is fronted by google apps. So this was much easier: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/

Comment: by doing this, are you still able to retrieve a student's metadata or profile information?

Comment: Yes, some, depending on what the college allows

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to add your config file to the initializer:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_after Rack::ETag, Rack::Saml,
 {
   :metadata => "#{Rails.root}/config/metadata.yml",
   :config => "#{Rails.root}/config/rack-saml.yml"
 }
```

And the saml_idp setting in the rack-saml.yml must match the key for the idp_lists entry in your metadata.yml